# File in use exception when attempting to move between directories

Tags: java, file, move

Just for kicks I was experimenting and trying to make a program that would move all the files from my  D:\Downloads directory that were installers to my G:\Downloads\Installers directory. I thought I had it working but upon using it, it returns "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

Here is the code and any input would be appreciated.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
public class FileOrganizer { 

public static void main(String[] args) {

File folder = new File("d:/Downloads");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
  if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
      String name = listOfFiles[i].getName();
      if (name.indexOf("Setup") > -1) {
          Path source = Paths.get("d:/Downloads");
          Path target = Paths.get("g:/Downloads/Installers");         
          try {
              Files.move(source, 
                         target.resolve(source.getFileName())), 
                         StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);}
               catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
          }
    }
    }  
    }     
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to make absolutely sure: you don't have windows explorer open or anything like that?

Comment: Correct. That was my first thought as well but as far as I can see nothing is using the directory whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change file name of each file, if file name is changeable then file is not used by any other process. You can not trace it with eyes, because there can be any thread which use it. After check each file, move it.

```
File sourceFile = ...;      
boolean changeableSource = source.renameTo(sourceFile);

File destFile = ...;
boolean changeableSource = destFile.renameTo(destFile);

if(changeableSource && changeableSource ){
   //Moving here...
}
```